# Scheduling according to the available memory of the node

Tags: kubernetes

How to set it up. When the available memory of the node is less than 8G, the node is set to be unschedulable, and when the memory is restored to more than 8G, it will automatically become schedulable. When the node is set to be unschedulable, the above pod continues to run unaffected

Or set the pod so that the pod is not scheduled to a node with less than 8G memory,Because the memory required by different pods is very different, it cannot be solved by setting the request

I set the configuration file of node. evictionHard:memory.available: 8Gi. but The pod running on the node will be evicted when the available memory of the node is less than 8G

Comment: It seems like requesting 8 GB of memory has exactly the effect you expect; the Pod won't get scheduled on a Node that has less than that amount of memory (counting Pod's memory requests and not actual utilization).  What different behavior do you want?

Comment: Different pods have different memory usage and it is not known when the pod is created. Some only need 100M and some need 6G. It would be a waste of resources if all pods set request (8G)  @David Maze

Comment: What should happen if a node has 7 GB free, and it will in fact turn out that a given pod only needs 100 MB?

Comment: Pod that require 100M memory will not be scheduled to this node. The essential requirement is to leave 8G margin for each node for the pods running on this node. Because the memory demand of the pod may suddenly increase during the running process, 8g is reserved as a buffer